# SQL using JOIN or not using IF into mysql sentence

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use join (optional) or not in case of:

```
if 
   join
else
   blank (join does'n exists)
```

is it posible?

Comment: What do you mean by joint does not exist? Please discribe your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a *left* outer join:

```
select ...
from table1
left join table2 on ...
```

will return all rows from table1, but null values for table2 if there is no matching rows in table2